# Is Bayesian approach best for this problem and if so, how do I calculate likelihood?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I have 5 years of solar irradiance (power) data measured at a particular location. I would like to understand whether the measured data, which very often is not accurate and has integrity issues, is coming from the same distribution as 14 years of measured data from a nearby location from a verified source.

Although the data is collected at 15-minute intervals year-round, in order to make this comparison we need to aggregate the instantaneous power readings to get energy per time period.  This is because January 8 AM readings don't follow the same distribution as January 3 PM readings and June 8 AM readings.

It is common practice to rollup power readings and compare energy at an annual level.  In this way we actually have just 5 datapoints from the test site and 14 datapoints from the verified site.  Even if we were to aggregate at the monthly level, we would need to compare month-by-month (i.e. January distribution between test and verified site) and still have the same data limitation.

Thus, we can't use frequentist methods and it seems we can frame this in a Bayesian way.  Namely, if we calculate the posterior odds, we can avoid having to calculate the probability of the data:

$$\frac{P(TargetData \cap VerifiedData | belief_0) * P(belief_0)}{P(TargetData \cap VerifiedData | belief_1) * P(belief_1)}$$

where belief<sub>0</sub> is that the datasets are from the same distribution and belief<sub>1</sub> are that they are not.

If this is the correct formulation framework, then the challenge is calculating the likelihoods.  Given that the data are from the same distribution, how would we estimate the probability of seeing the data from both datasets?

Once we get this Bayes factor, we can make a conclusion about the strength of belief<sub>0</sub> over belief<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: I do not follow your rationale against frequentist methods at all. The problem seems to be in specifying the analysis: are you comparing *monthly* or *annual* results? A statistician immediately sees this as a repeated measures problem for which there are Bayesian or frequentist methods. A simple repeated measures ANOVA comes to mind, at least as a comparison of means.

Comment: Secondly, while it's appealing to immediately jump to the idea of setting your "belief" as a prior, a wheels and a motor does not a car make. . For instance, your "verified data" come from a sample that has variability and may not be different from the truth. If you set aside, for the moment, the issue of repeated measures, it would be hard not to justify this analysis as a type of t-test, because your "belief" may be that the verified data are the "truth" and the "truth" is 3, but what would you say if those data were actually 2?

Comment: Thirdly, for Bayesians, the probability itself is the belief, not the parameter. For the Bayesian, "updating your belief" means estimating a posterior. But your language and description of the problem are firmly rooted in a decision theoretic framework, i.e. "I would like to understand [if] the ... data ... [come] from the same distribution...". They either do or they don't. Decision theoretic Bayes has, in my mind, all the same problems of NHST at the cost of more complicated math.

Comment: The rationale against frequentist methods is that they are not robust to small sample sizes.

I'll have to think upon your 2nd and 3rd points.  As for the first point, the level at which we specify the comparison is a modeling decision and is up to us.  It doesn't matter, as long as we get to the answer - 'To what degree can I trust the data from the test site?'.  In my description, I was merely stating that it is customary to analyze the data at the annual level.  Doesn't the repeated measurements ANOVA that you propose break down when there are 14 samples?

Comment: No, not if the distributional assumptions are met, especially when the aggregated data has a high degree of precision.

Comment: By distributional assumptions, do you mean the 4 annual datapoints are approximate a normal distribution?  It's hard to assess normality from 4 datapoints.

Comment: I do mean that, but I don't mean that you need to or should assess it. It turns out there's little value in formally testing assumptions, rather if any point is egregiously out of whack, it immediately requires other efforts. When values are aggregated up using a mean, as you have proposed, you can make a stronger argument that limit-laws have kicked in and provide the necessary stability of observations.

Comment: The annual measurements aren't a mean.  The raw level measurements are point estimates of power at every 15 minutes.  We divide each power measurement by 1/4 to get the energy in a 15 minute interval (units would be kW-quarter hour / m^2).  We then add all these up to get the total energy in a year (kWh/m^2).